# war-file as a part of container or shared folder when running docker

Tags: docker

So I run jBoss as application server and I package my application in a war. When dockerizing this I end up having to choose between two very different ways of doing it.

What is the "Right Way" of the two following.

A) Create a jBoss-docker image but don't add the war-file. On startup copy the war-file from a mounted/shared folder and do this on every invokation of the jBoss-docker.

B) Create a new docker image for each release, containing the jBoss server WITH the war-file already in the correct location.

A seems faster for me when developing. I don't have to re-build the image several times per day.

B seems more correct, one image to ship around between development, test, integration and production. But very cumbersome to have to re-build so often.